# Acronym tags should be synonyms of full spelled-out tag

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There is a [Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/19/do-all-schools-of-bjj-come-from-the-same-root) tagged with [bjj](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bjj) and [brazilian-jiu-jitsu](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brazilian-jiu-jitsu) with the former pointing to the latter.

Likewise, [mma](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mma) (no questions are tagged with this) should also point to [mixed-martial-arts](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-martial-arts) (which does have one question tagged at this time).

Comment: This is kind of the point of tag synonyms; not everyone will instinctually use the same spelling, the same name, etc... A good example of this can be `jiu-jitsu` (which stemmed from an older and largely deprecated transliteration system) and `jujutsu` (which is the more widely accepted spelling).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set up a synonym from [bjj](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bjj) to [brazilian-jiu-jitsu](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brazilian-jiu-jitsu).

When other tags show up that need synonyms, we can set that up too. Don't worry about trying to catch them all up front - there are likely too many tags to consider and it'd be easier to just handle them as they come up.

Answer (score 4):

Would someone with the requisite permissions please make [mma](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mma) a synonym of [mixed-martial-arts](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-martial-arts)?

Comment: Done! I've created a synonym so mma will not point to mixed-martial-arts.