# Create tag for "Historic European Martial Arts"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I suggest `historic-european`.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_European_martial_arts

I found it missing for this [question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/8235/is-jogo-do-pau-stickfighting-derived-from-longsword-fighting).

Answer (score 3):

We should standardize on a single tag for historic European martial arts. There was a previously existing [hema](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hema) tag.

I have made [hema](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hema) a synonym of [historic-european](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historic-european), in keeping with [Acronym tags should be synonyms of full spelled-out tag](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15/5961).

Comment: Can historic-European be a synonym then?

Comment: @DanielReis Sure. We may actually want the acronym HEMA to point to historic-European because the spelled-out version is clearer. But we should collect these under one synonym or the other.

Comment: I have proposed a synonym. First time doing it, so hopefully it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Added.

Please [write up a wiki entry for it](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/447).